# How do I find all Twitter handles from a text file using grep?

Tags: regex

Here's my dilemma:

```
I really like @somecrazytwitterhandle; he's so cool!
@somecrazytwitterhandle is the best! His email is cth1983@gmail.com.
```

So initially I thought I needed to search for the following - 
"\ @[^\ ]*" 
however this doesn't work because some Twitter ids. can start at the beginning of a line as seen above.

So then how do I search for the above? I wanted to do something like this, but I don't know the syntax ... "[^|\ ]@[^\ ]*" where the first bracket is an or ... for either at the beginning of a line *or* has a space before an "@" symbol.

Comment: `\B` might work, it's the negation of a word boundary. If `@` was preceded by a letter a digit or `_` there'd be a word boundary (`@` would end the previous word), but if `@` follows a space or is at the start of the line there's no word boundary. [Works for PCRE at least](https://regex101.com/r/D5RC7N/1)

Comment: `@[\w]*?(?=[^\w])` Works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep -o` with `tr`:

```
grep -oE '(^|[[:blank:]])@[[:alnum:]_]+' f | tr -d '[[:blank:]]'
```

```
@somecrazytwitterhandle
@somecrazytwitterhandle
```

- Regex `@[[:alnum:]_]+` matches a text that starts with `@` followed by 1+ word characters.
- `tr -d '[[:blank:]]'` strips all whitespaces from output

Comment: I added an email b/c this is what's causing me grief.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a PCRE regex with a GNU `grep` like this:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\S)@\w+' file
```

The `P` option enables the PCRE regex engine and `o` makes it return only the matched texts.

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind makes sure there is start of string or a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location.

The `@\w+` will match a `@` and then 1+ letters, digits or `_`.

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/cTVvmm):

```
s="I really like @somecrazytwitterhandle; he's so cool!
@somecrazytwitterhandle is the best!"
grep -Po '(?<!\S)@\w+' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
@somecrazytwitterhandle
@somecrazytwitterhandle
```

Alternative solution is to use `\B`:

```
grep -Po '\B@\w+' <<< "$s"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/B5GazC). `\B` is a position other than a word boundary, and `@` must be preceded with a non-word char or start of string then.

Comment: What is an email address also exists in the text?

Answer (score 0):

`@[\w]*?(?=[^\w])` Will Match Twitter handles and will also match ones with numbers and underscores